# Want to use the HTTP-REFERER of in an HTML page through Javascript

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I Want to use  the HTTP-REFERER of in an HTML page. Is it possible to do it with a JavaScript included in the page itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referring page can be accessed via `document.referrer`. Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('This page was referred to from:' + document.referrer);
</script>
```